# Is there any way to open an "incognito" Terminal/shell?

Tags: terminal, shell

Under normal circumstances, a command typed in a Terminal/shell can be retrieved later via history command or other means.

Is there any way to have an "incognito" Terminal/shell, i.e. one whose commands are not remembered in any way after it is closed?

One use for this would be to charge a credit card, or perform other security sensitive commands.

A potential answer is to boot a Linux "Live CD" and then shut it down. Any other (easier) approaches that would work in OS X/Linux/Windows?

Answer (score 8):

You did not specify which shell you are using but:

The `HISTFILE` environment variable defines where the history is stored. With

```
unset HISTFILE
```

you can tell bash to stop recording commands. You can re-enable it with

```
export HISTFILE=${HOME}/.bash_history
```

From `man bash`:

```
HISTFILE
       The name of the file in which command history is saved (see  HISTORY  below).   The  default
       value  is  ~/.bash_history.   If unset, the command history is not saved when an interactive
       shell exits.
```

Comment: Is this the only file that keeps any history? If I delete something private from there, can I be sure it won't be anywhere else too?

Comment: It is the only place where the shell stores the history but if something else (e.g., a backup program) copies the history file somewhere else you will have to delete it also there.

Comment: @Matteo This does not seem to be entirely true.  In Mac OSX's Terminal, if I do: `unset HISTFILE; sudo echo sensitive_command`, then `sudo grep -r "[s]ensitive_command" /` ... I can see the command in `/private/var/log/system.log`.

Comment: After a bit of testing, only successful sudo commands appear to be logged in `/private/var/log/system.log` (sudo commands only, even as root user).